# Why InnoDB adds index for foreign key column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

MySQL auto adding index when adding foreign key to a column In MySQL with innoDB engine. Primary key is enough for search the rows, how affect the performance by adding index for foreign key column.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL docs state the reasoning clearly behind this [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the
>   referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key
>   columns are listed as the first columns in the same order. Such an
>   index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not
>   exist.

There are many queries typically joins which require rows to match on the basis of foreign keys and database has to find those rows. The index typically helps this to do faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an foreign key means this column will be used to join data with any other tables referenced column, so it is understood that index will be required on this column for better join.

Due to this reason this feature is in build in mysql foreign key concept.